# SQL Server execution plan for diffierent Top count

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on an API that expose data of a legacy view in SQL Server and met performance issue, the response is extremely slow. This view has 10+ joined tables and kind of a complex `where` condition. The total number of rows of the view is approx. 7000.

After test I found that the execution time is related to top count.

1. If top is 15, it takes ~10s
2. If top is 50, it takes ~500ms
3. With binary search, I found the boundary is 30

Top 15 and top 50 have different execution plans. Finally I add `option(recompile)` to make average response about 800ms, which is still slow but acceptable.

My question is why this happens? Is there any way to let SQL Server choose the faster execution plan for top 15 without `option(recompile)`?

Comment: Posting the query plans (use [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)) and the queries would be a useful started, along with the DDL of your `VIEW`.

Comment: Also if you really want it fast, consider putting all or most of the view logic in an Indexed View. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This view is not that highly used, getting result in ~1s is acceptable, just curious why that happend so that I can handle simalar issue later.

Comment: Row goal  issue can be accrued in your query https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals.Could you try DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL hint.

Comment: Show me the view code, let's optimize it.